Help with proving the von Roos kinetic energy operator is Hermitian
When calculating the kinetic energy of a variable mass quantum system, such as a semiconductor heterostructure where mass has spatial variance due to the effective mass approximation, von Roos (Phys Rev B, 1983, 27(12), 7547) stipulated that the following operator (T) is Hermitian:
$$T=-\frac{\hbar}{4}\\{m(x)^\alpha\frac{d}{dx}m(x)^\beta\frac{d}{dx}m(x)^{-(\alpha+\beta+1)}+ m(x)^{-(\alpha+\beta+1)}\frac{d}{dx}m(x)^\beta\frac{d}{dx}m(x)^\alpha\\}$$
Note that the $m(x)^{-(\alpha+\beta+1)}$ is necessary to impart the correct (1/mass) units. What I am curious about is how to prove that this is indeed the case. It strikes me that the above may simply be the sum of an operator and it's transpose, which is automatically Hermitian. At the same time, usually Hermiticity is demonstrated by integration by parts, and for this problem I can't seem to figure out an effective approach with that (I've tried and failed, but perhaps I'm getting lost in the algebra since there is a double derivative in the integral). Any ideas?

@ACuriousMind Is that a policy, or you made it up?
